# Codeigniter Ajax - Passing Filelist always get NULL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm trying to upload image to server with ajax and codeigniter php backend, the file select is working

```
FileList {0: File, length: 1}
File {name: "21430081_1852077344807727_5107330097727092003_n.jpg", lastModified: 1504942183875, lastModifiedDate: Sat Sep 09 2017 14:29:43 GMT+0700 (WIB), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 25179, …}
```

the file is "not null" but when i send this filelist via ajax to  my controller, the result

```
{datas: "NULL"}
datas : "NULL"
```

the controller must return image url in the server (http://localhost/upload_folder/file.jpg)

my controller code

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'file'));
        $this->load->library(array('upload','user_agent'));
        //error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);                
    }

    public function post_image()
    {
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
            "allowed_types" => "jpg|png|jpeg",
            "upload_path"   => "./uploads/",
        ));
        $image = $this->input->post('image');
        if($this->upload->do_upload($image))
       // if(is_object($image))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->get_upload_data();
            echo json_encode(['datas' => base_url().$data[0]['file_name']]);
        }else
        {
            echo json_encode(['datas' => "error"]);
        }
    }

}
```

My ajax code

```
function saveToServer(file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', file);
    //console.log(fd.get('image'));
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/Ajax/post_image",
        type : "POST",

        data : {'image' : fd},
        processData: false,
        contentType : false,
        success : function(datas) {
            // do something
            const url = JSON.parse(datas).data;
            insertToEditor(url);
        }
    });
}
```

i'm retrieve image file using this code

```
function selectLocalImage() {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'image-input')
    input.click();

    // Listen upload local image and save to server
    input.onchange = () => {
        const file = input.files;

        // file type is only image.
        //if (/^jpg\//.test(file.type)) {
            saveToServer(file);
            console.log(file);
        //} else {
        //    console.warn('You could only upload images.');
        //}
    };
}
```

Comment: **Just a tip:** I find it is best to autoload the database library in config/autoload.php instead of using this `$this->load->database();` save you placing it every where.

Answer (score 0):

This is my "fix" for my question above.
When i check the `$_POST` or in `$image = $this->input->post('image');` it always NULL, but when i check `$_FILES`, it return the file i post from view, so i change (almost) the whole function to native PHP upload file

```
if ($_FILES['image'] !== null){
                        //$image = $this->input->post($_FILES['image']['name']);
                        //$this->upload->do_multi_upload($image);
                        $target_dir = "./uploads/";
                        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
                        $uploadOk = 1;
                        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
                        {
                            $data = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
                            echo json_encode(['data' => 'uploads/'.$_FILES["image"]["name"]]);
                        }else
                        {
                            //echo json_encode(['datas' => gettype($image)]);
                            echo json_encode("not uploaded!");
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        echo json_encode("nothing!");
                    }
```

its not best solution but i have fixed my problem (for now).